# Sonar Admin Password Lost

Tags: sonarqube

I have lost my sonar admin password, unable to login. I have go through below link which says to execute a sql query for password updation but I don't have sonar database installed.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication#Authentication-FAQ

Can anybody knows is there any way to regenerate password without using database.
Please guide me for the same..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have access to the db, you will have to ask to another admin to change your password for you.

If there's no other admin and you do not have db access, being able to reset the admin account means that you would be indeed able to reset admin account of any SonarQube installation!

Comment: "to reset admin account you need access to admin account", This is a good analogy but it is a little flawed, If I had access to admin account why would I need to reset admin account? I have local access to the instance and yet I don't even know how to reset its password. and yes If I had local access to every sonarcube installation I should be able to reset their admin account password.

Comment: @AaA I'm not sure to understand your comment, what is exactly the problem you are encountering ?

Comment: I was testing software a few months back meaning just installed according to quick start document, then followed a few other documents to remove rules and add other rules. then we get busy with other projects and evaluation was halted. when I came back to this project, I couldn't remember the password, which means I have to start over. "Any person who has physical access to the data store of a project should be able to modify its data" this is a true statement, and seems sonarcube is ignoring it. I think Your software need to allow means of resetting password by local access as a last resort.

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing your use case in more details! If you have physical access to the computer where SonarQube is installed, you can restore the admin password by using a SQL query that we're providing.

Comment: Please read "Reinstating Admin Access" in https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/ to get all the details about it.

Comment: Yes, I did read that before coming here. Where would you like me to run that command (SQL I believe?)

Comment: If you need more help with this issue, I recommend you to ask for help on https://community.sonarsource.com/c/help/sq/10. People from the team will be able to help you